# Facebook Login not working - nonexisting field on node type (AnonymousUser)

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

My app has Facebook Login. It has suddenly stop working. It is always login user as anonymous, so I am not getting any data. How to stop anonymous login for my App.

OAuthException, code: 100, message: (#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (first_name) on node type (AnonymousUser), x-fb-trace-id: EQfRXtpQzk4 [HTTP 400]

SDK version 5.5.1 GA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a Facebook issue and there is an opened bug on their platform:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/173424853153369/